# convert .csv to a .xlsx from CLI

Tags: linux, csv, xlsx

I found this for the opposite conversion [Convert xlsx to text CSV via command line only on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746295/convert-xlsx-to-text-csv-via-command-line-only-on-linux)
But I have absolutely no understanding of that line of code.  Can anyone tell me how to convert from a csv to a xlsx from the CLI?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a read through this http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/370ee470-f2cd-4f30-a167-b106dd51d47a. Looks like what you're looking for ?

Comment: it looks like that's for windows and i need it for linux

Comment: I've found this, http://www.python-excel.org/, you could write a batch script that creates an xls file, inputs the CSV file and then saves it. That should do the trick?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you can try unoconv, which uses libreoffice as backend. It can convert between formats really easily:

```
unoconv -f xls myfile.csv
```

Sadly it does not support xlsx on Fedora, but supports ooxml - Microsoft Excel 2003 XML [.xml]

Comment: Not a standalone program: «For Document conversions is needed that is LibreOffice or OpenOffice installed» :-( .

Comment: Also good to know it exports based on comma delimited values, not semicolon