# Convert .csv to xlsx using bash shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I'm trying to convert pipe delimited .csv file to .xlsx using bash shell scripting. Tried the below shell script. csv file has valid records. The script is converting .csv to .xlsx but when I tried opening the Excel file, it says file format or file extension is not valid. How to convert .csv to .xlsx using shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.csv; do 
mv -- "$f" "${f%.csv}.xlsx"
done
```

Comment: .xlsx is a proprietary format by Microsoft. `mv` does not convert the file, it just renames it. The content remains the same. Excel can open and read properly formatted .csv file. So why trying to change the format in the first place?

Comment: I want to convert .csv to .xlsx format

Comment: .xlsx file is a zip file that contains the data in xml format. That's not going to happen by renaming the file. You need a tool or a library to do something like that. And asking for tool / library suggestions is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158254/convert-csv-to-xls-file-on-linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert .csv to a .xlsx from CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845162/convert-csv-to-a-xlsx-from-cli)